# How to show ajax modalpop up using jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

When i click on a button in the repeater, i wanna display an ajax modal popup using jquery. I am trying to do that, but its not getting displayed.

How to solve this issue? Any suggestions???

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far so that it can be fixed?

Comment: It would help if you showed how you are `trying` to do it.

Comment: Post the javascript code along with the html. That would help us a lot ;-)

Comment: What i am doing is that, as i told i have a repeater, i am adding an attribute to the edit button in the Item_dataBound.
imgEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick"
                        , string.Format("Edit('{0}'",pnlPopup.ClientId));

and in the javascript.
<script type="javascript">
function Edit(popup)
{
$('#'+ popup).show();
}
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the dialog.

```
$(function() {

            $('#panel_clientid').dialog({
                minWidth: 400,
                minHeight: 200,
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                title: 'My title',
                autoOpen: false,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'explode'
            });
};
```